# PHP - localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, php

I'm currently trying to get php , apache and mysql up and running on Ubuntu. I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu to learn. But i'm facing a bit of a problem. When the code is correct the file gets executed properly in browser, where as when there is an syntax error, instead of showing the error in browser it throws an error as shown.

[HTTP 500 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x98iS.png)

I've checked my php setting via phpinfo() and its as follows.
[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJdPX.png)

I think error reporting is enabled, and I've tried reading similar other questions on the various threads,but they didn't really help me out. They pointed out that i need to verify that .htaccess file is in good shape. I'm not exactly sure how do i verify that, can anyone help me out? I've also tried changing directory permissions to 777 and 755 but that didn't help either. Any idea as to how can i fix it?

Comment: The value `dispay_errors` is `off` needs to be `on`...

Comment: server root is /var/www for older versions of `Ubuntu 14.04 -`, and `/var/www/html` for `Ubuntu 14.04 +`, then `sudo service apache2 restart` is the old way for `Ubuntu 14.04` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2` is for` Ubuntu 16.04` __but if you use sudo service for Ubuntu 16.04 it will still go__.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You `display_errors` directive is set to `no`.

To fix this:

1. Edit `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` and set:

   ```
   ; display_errors
   ;   Default Value: On
   ;   Development Value: On
   ;   Production Value: Off

   ; display_startup_errors
   ;   Default Value: Off
   ;   Development Value: On
   ;   Production Value: Off


   #to 

   ; display_errors
   ;   Default Value: On
   ;   Development Value: On
   ;   Production Value: On

   ; display_startup_errors
   ;   Default Value: On
   ;   Development Value: On
   ;   Production Value: On
   ```
2. Restart your apache with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
3. To have the same behaviour on the `cli` edit the `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`
4. To set this value locally add this to a `.htaccess` file in the server root: `/var/www/html`

Do

```
    vim .htaccess
```

Press `i`

Type the following:

```
    # Displaying php errors
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 6143
```

Press
      
<kbd>Esc</kbd>
      `:x`
      <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note:**

Mine was `php version 7.0`. Change to your particular version. And in your image both `local` and `master` values are both set to `Off` so:

1. `step 1` will change the `master value`, and
2. `step 4` will change the `local value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @George , the first step worked for me. I still have a few doubts. When you say .htaccess file in server root, is it the `/etc/apache2` directory?   Also is there any difference between `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: server root is `/var/www` for older versions of `Ubuntu 14.04 -`, and `/var/www/html` for `Ubuntu 14.04 +`, then `sudo service apache2 restart` is the old way for `Ubuntu 14.04` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2` is for `Ubuntu 16.04` but if you __use sudo service for Ubuntu 16.04 it will still go__

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following lines of code to your PHP file for temporary configuration

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix now this way

1 : /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

2: ; error_reporting
   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
   Development Value: E_ALL
   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
3 : sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more descriptive?